# Xcode 7: Command failed due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11

Tags: xcode, swift, xcode7

I realize there is another question about this, but none of the answers helped me.

**Every single Xcode project** I have has this same error:

```
Command failed due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11
```

It lists nearly all of the swift files I've created in the project as having the error.

Other Notes:

I store my files on iCloud Drive (so that I can work on them from any computer).

Last week, iCloud added a suffix of ".folder" to my project file names. Perhaps there is another glitch going on from the iCloud side of things. But not one I can find.

I have tried commenting out lines of code, but seeing as this is a problem across all of my projects (2 of which I know worked perfectly yesterday) I don't think it is a problem with just one project's code.

Answer (score 0):

After much searching I went to the obvious thing, which for some reason I had not done yet:

REBOOT my Mac

Now everything works perfectly after a quick boot clean CMD + Shift + K